# Using storyboard?.instantiate returns "Unexpectedly found nil" error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting an error when I use `storyboard?.instantiate`. It's giving me this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and this is my code:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectedViewController") 
             as? SelectedViewController
    vc?.name = imgArr[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

and I am already using the identifier `ID` in this photo:

[image: go to the photo from here]

Please anyone can help me in this issue.

Comment: How do you initialize the storyboard variable?

Comment: The instantiating VC has to be in the hierarchy as well, called from a VC which has the entry point or down on its chain, otherwise it will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the mouse over the class field in IB , then click enter , module check must be ticked , and verify you correctly set storyboard identifier

[image]

Comment: Thank you it's working now after I checked the "inherit module from target" :)

Answer (score 0):

is SelectedViewController in the same storyboard of the collection view's view controller?

I always prefer to unwrap optionals with a guard or if let to avoid crashes like this. You can use:

```
   guard let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectedViewController") as? SelectedViewController else { "return error here if wanted" return }
    viewController.name = imgArr[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: it's giving me an error called "Unknown class SelectedViewController in Interface Builder file."

Answer (score 0):

try this below code:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vcTitles =  storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcTitles") as! VCTitlesViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcTitles, animated: true)
```